# Suppress XML from being rendered

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

So first time so please admit tiny issues.

I am working on an app which getting slow while it grows. We have implemented one app for different branches of our company and making part visible or not by a big configuration file.

Problem is now regardless whether a part of the form is visible or not. He always initiate the controller of the non visible part. That all cost time and makes the application lame.

I am searching for way to suppress the initiating of the controller. When i remember the alloy annotation correctly there was a "rendered" attribute which is now not available anymore.

Has someone an idea how i could realize this?

Answer (score 0):

So i used an attribute called "rendered" and let the controller react to it. It helps to boost the performance dramatically.

Further i noticed the the pure mass of visible information also slows down the performance of the iPad so i used a scrollable view to put information on. That also accelerate the app.